# Render paragraph reference field in page.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

In **page.html.twig** I want to **show a paragraph reference field** which contains a left and right text_field.

The **name of the reference field** in the node is: **field_intro**. That field is linked to a paragraph type named: text_left_right

Using below code I can render the paragraphs, but if I add an extra field to the paragraph type, it is not updated. I would like to render all fields, even if I add a new field in the future.

That is not going to happen with this piece of code:

```
{% for item in node.field_intro %}
  {{ item.entity.field_left.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

I found a lot of answers for rendering in node.html.twig but not in page.html.twig.

**UPDATE after below comments and answer:**
It is not recommended to print fields in a page.html.twig page. Better use views or blocks to establish what you need. And if you want to use templates, use node.html.twig.

Comment: Fields are meant to be inside of node.html.twig. If you want to render them in page.html then you're going out of the content area. If I was you, I either would use a Views block to display the paragraphs or create a block type and add the paragraphs there.

Comment: Do you mean `adding a new field value to the same existing field` (cardinality) or really `adding a completely new field with a new field name`?

Comment: @no-sssweat: I thought because the 'node' is available it is ok to use it in the page template?

Comment: @Hudri: adding a new field in the paragraph type text_left_right

Comment: Don't do this. Its a calculable risk on single field values (e.g. the famous hero image), but a really bad idea when used for everything. Better go with views or blocks.

Comment: I advise to use the render pipeline instead of print directly. You can create a view block to render a node in a particular view mode.

Comment: @Lance you're correct, just not my preferred approach.

Comment: Can I conclude that we better do not print fields in page.html.twig. And if needed better use views or blocks in regions? And if a node needs a more advanced structure, it is better to implement that html structure in node.html.twig itself? (e.g. if you combine full-width content areas with fixed areas?) And simplify the page.html.twig structure?

Comment: It's not the page templates job to print node fields, which is why you are running into this. The typical pattern is to create a view mode of the node, which has its own template and markup, then render a node with it with Views (or programmatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but if I add an extra field to the paragraph type, it is not updated.
>   I would like to render all fields, even if I add a new field in the
>   future.

To answer the question, you just need to loop though the paragraph fields.

```
{% for item in node.field_intro %}
  {% for paragraph_field in item.entity %}
     {% if 'field_' in paragraph_field %}
       {{ paragraph_field.value }}
     {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {{ item.entity.paragraph_field.value }} must be {{ paragraph_field.value }} I guess? And this is also printing other fields like ID, revision_id, ...

Comment: @Lance I have fixed it.